# I want to insert record in excel from 5th row to nth row using oledb connection. anyone having any code

Tags: c#, oledb

I want to insert record in excel start from 5th row to nth row using OleDbConnection connection. anyone having any code in c#, it will be really helpfull for me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have 3 columns in your excel table

```
        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();

        connStringBuilder.DataSource =tmpFilePath;  // Set path to excel file
        connStringBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
        connStringBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0;HDR=NO");

        string connectionString = connStringBuilder.ConnectionString;

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            DataTable objSheetNames = conn.GetSchema("Tables");

            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO [{0}](F1,F2,F3) VALUES('{1}','{2}','{3}');",
                        objSheetNames.Rows[0][2], "", "", "");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
```